# How to set airflow schedule_interval to execute only between 0 and 30 minutes past the hour

Tags: python, cron, airflow, scheduler

I have an Airflow DAG that runs every hour. However, I need to schedule it only between the 0~30 minute of each hour.

Example:
11:00-12:00
12:00-13:35
14:00-

Setting "0-30/60 * * * *" does not apply the desired condition to execute only between 0 and 30 minutes past the hour.
To achieve the desired schedule where the task runs only after the previous schedule has ended and between 0 and 30 minutes past the hour?

Comment: Look into using the `TimeSensor` as part of your DAG definition

Comment: If use a TimeSensor, the DAG remain in a running state while the sensor is waiting. Is there any way to resolve this issue by setting the schedule_interval?

Comment: To prevent a new run from starting if the previous run has not finished, you can set catchup=False in your DAG definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To schedule a cron job to run every hour between minutes 0 and 30, you can use the following cron expression:

```
0-30 * * * *
```

To prevent a new run from starting if the previous run has not finished, you can set `catchup=False` in your DAG definition